# Is it good to have dedicated ExecutorService for Spring Boot With Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, java-8

I have seen this code many times but don't know what is the advantage/disadvantage for it. In Spring Boot applications, I saw people define this bean.

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("heavyLoadBean")
public ExecutorService heavyLoadBean() {
    return Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
}
```

Then whenever a CompletableFuture object is created in the service layer, that heavyLoadBean is used.

```
public CompletionStage<T> myService() {
   return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doingVeryBigThing(), heavyLoadBean);
}
```

Then the controller will call the service.

```
@GetMapping("/some/path")
public CompletionStage<SomeModel> doIt() {
   return service.myService();
}
```

I don't see the point of doing that. Tomcat in Spring Boot has x number of threads. All the threads are used to process user requests. What is the point of using a different thread pool here? Anyway the user expects to see response coming back.

Comment: There can be many reasons to do this. 

First of all, tomcat's default executor (and the associated threadpool) is for processing web-requests. In my opinion, if you have a hibernate, Spring boot creates a separate pool for database connections.

Having said that, even though it is a questionable design and design-pattern, your app may require a separate executor service for long-running things. An example is an ETL job triggered from a REST call (async one). For this to work, you probably needs to maintain a separate executor service as you described.

Comment: I agree with you to use this approach if it's background process/scheduled ones or long running processes. But here it's returned back to the user.

Comment: What it returns is the Future object (assuming it can be converted to xml/json appropriately). A Future object holds status and a link to the returned object (in the form of an uuid?). If that's the case, user (over the REST call) can obtain the status of the job and the return value by querying using the job uuid.

Comment: Very interesting. But I haven't see the result in form of uuid. Do you have an example?

Comment: My above answer was theory. Refer to the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

You can call isDone and get methods to check the status or get the result. However, if you send it as xml/json over the web, the connection with the actual job may lost (or not). Theoretically, you can embed a uuid (or something similar) in the serialization of such class and maintain a storage (map) of the id and job. 

Without referring to fuller code base, that's all I can say right now.

Comment: I believe in that theory also. But haven't seen that supported in Spring.

Comment: unless there is *really* some work stealing going on - that is you can split your task into smaller pieces that can be processed independently, this has no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

`CompletableFuture` is used process the tasks asynchronously, suppose in your application if you have two tasks independent of each other then you can execute two tasks concurrently (to reduce the processing time)

```
public CompletionStage<T> myService() {
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doingVeryBigThing(), heavyLoadBean);
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doingAnotherBigThing(), heavyLoadBean);
}
```

In the above example `doingVeryBigThing()` and `doingAnotherBigThing()` two tasks which are independent of each other, so now these two tasks will be executed concurrently with two different threads from `heavyLoadBean` thread pool, try below example will print the two different thread names.

```
public CompletionStage<T> myService() {
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName(), heavyLoadBean);
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName(), heavyLoadBean);
}
```

If you don't provide the thread pool, by default supplied `Supplier` will be executed by `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`

**public static  CompletableFuture supplyAsync(Supplier supplier)**

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() with the value obtained by calling the given Supplier.

**public static  CompletableFuture supplyAsync(Supplier supplier,
                                                   Executor executor)**

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the given executor with the value obtained by calling the given Supplier.

Comment: what is the difference of running both doingVeryBigThing() and doingAnotherBigThing() in default common pool and in the heavyLoadBean pool?

Comment: Big difference is how you configure that with properties, take a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

Comment: Are you saying this approach helps the main thread not to be locked up by these big processes?

Comment: yes, main thread will execute the rest of the part when thread from `heavyLoadBean` thread pool executes `doingVeryBigThing()` @TrongBang

Comment: I think it's clearer to put the main reason as not being locked up.

Comment: i think that's not good way to say, understanding `supplyAsync` should make it clear @TrongBang

Answer (score -1):

Please check comments in the main post and other solutions. They will give you more understanding of java 8 CompletableFuture. I'm just not feeling the right answer was given though.

From our discussions, I can see the purpose of having a different thread pool instead of using the default thread pool is that the default thread pool is also used by the main web server (spring boot - tomcat). Let's say 8 threads.

If we use up all 8 threads, server appears to be irresponsive. However, if you use a different thread pool and exhaust that thread pool with your long running processes, you will get a different errors in your code. Therefore, the server can still response to other user requests.

Correct me if I'm wrong.